# Mysql 5.5 to Mysql 5.6 upgrade Insert query is breaking

Tags: mysql, insert, type-conversion

Assume column with the following definition

```
product_id      INT   NULL     NO_DEFAULT
product_id_nn   INT   NOT NULL NO_DEFAULT
```

and query

```
insert into table (product_id,product_id_nn) values ('','')
```

the above query works in Mysql 5.5. `it will insert NULL value for product_id and`0`for product_id_nn`.

the same query breaks in Mysql 5.6 and informs you that wrong type data is getting passed.

Yes, I am 100% accepting Mysql 5.6 statement, `however why it was working in 5.5` and as you expect it's huge `old php` application breaking the functionality with 5.6

Any setting to make it work like 5.5?

Comment: What was/is the value of `sql_mode`?

Comment: @RickJames, `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 5.6.12:  (Well, not really an answer, but more info.)

```
mysql> insert into se108833 (product_id,product_id_nn) values ('','');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'product_id' at row 1    |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'product_id_nn' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from se108833;
+------------+---------------+
| product_id | product_id_nn |
+------------+---------------+
|          0 |             0 |
+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| sql_mode      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |  -- not "strict" mode
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set session sql_mode = 'strict_all_tables';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into se108833 (product_id,product_id_nn) values ('','');
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'product_id' at row 1
```